# java.lang.ClassCastException: erro em Converter JSF

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf-2.2

Eu estou implementando o Converter abaixo:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = Cargo.class)
public class CargoConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    private CargosRepository cargoRepository;

    public CargoConverter() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        Cargo retorno = null;

        if (value != null) {
            retorno = this.cargoRepository.porId(new Long(value));
        }
        return retorno;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value != null) {
            Long id = ((Cargo) value).getId();
            String retorno = (id == null ? null : id.toString());
            return retorno;
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

Na linha `Long id = ((Cargo value).getId()` está dando a exceção acima.

Meu model está implementado assim:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

No model também está implementado hasCode.

Como resolver esta exceção? O que estou fazendo de errado?

Exceção:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.model.Cargo
    at com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.converter.CargoConverter.getAsString(CargoConverter.java:31)
```

Comment: Qual exceção? Acho que esqueceu de inclui-la

Comment: `value` já está chegando para você como um `Long`, então não precisa fazer *cast* para um objeto `Cargo` e depois recuperar o *id*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando a exceção:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.model.Cargo
    at com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.converter.CargoConverter.getAsString(CargoConverter.java:31)
```

O que está acontecendo é que você tenta fazer *cast* de um objeto `Long` para um `Cargo`. `value` em `getAsString` já está chegando para você como `Long`, provavelmente é o `id` que espera e precisa, então não é necessário (e nem possível) fazer *cast* para o tipo `Cargo`, você pode alterar disto:

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value != null) {
        Long id = ((Cargo) value).getId();
        String retorno = (id == null ? null : id.toString());
        return retorno;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Para isto:

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    return value == null ? "" : value.toString();
}
```

Já considerando o valor final. A questão é que como `Object` você está retornando um `Cargo`. Não conheço como está o restante da sua aplicação, principalmente os locais que usam este *converter*, mas talvez aqui seja necessário retornar o `id` de `Cargo` também.